# CSS/Wordpress: can't change menu font size

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website and am trying to change the font size of the main menu. From Chrome, When I do an "inspect element" on the page I can see that the menu element is laid out thusly:

```
.blog-menu a {
   font-size: 13px;
}
```

When I change the font-size to another value from within inspect element, the change is properly displayed on the page. However when I add the code:

```
.blog-menu a {
   font-size: 25px;
}
```

to my style.css file, the change is not registered. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?  Probably something stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can often be caused by styles being applied from your cache. To clear your cache and reload the page, pressing CMD/CTRL+Shift+R (Mac OSX and Windows, respectively).

If the new style is still not being applied, it's possible that another style is overriding it. This can be caused by a style being applied after your code, or before your code with the `!important` tag.

Some questions that may help you figure this out:

What does your environment look like? Is your `style.css` in a child theme's folder? Is another stylesheet being called after your `style.css`?

---

Updated as per comment conversation:

```
<style type="text/css">
.blog-menu a 
{
  font-size: 25px !important;
}
</style>
<div class="blog-menu">
  <a>This should be 25px</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried clearing the cache, but the problem persists.

To answer your questions:

1.  Not sure what this means.  I *just* started designing my website.  The first thing I did was download a new theme (Hemingway) and made/started using a child theme of it.

2.  Yes the style.css is in a child theme folder.  I have successfully made 1 other change to the stlye (changed the background color of the menu in-question), via this same style.css.

3.  I don't think there is.  There shouldn't be, correct?

Comment: The parent theme is probably calling a style on that element after it includes the child theme. Add `!important` after your style, for example change `font-size: 25px;` to `font-size: 25px !important;`. This basically says "hey, use me even if someone puts another font-size attribute for this element". If that doesn't change it for you, then the theme author has defined the font-size with !important on it after the child theme is included, and the only way to fix it is to add the important tag on the element inline (from the WP text editor)

Comment: Let me know if the above does or doesn't work for you, or if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I tried adding the "!important" but there was no change.

How would I go about editing the element inline from the WP text editor?  Would I be editing another file?  In the parent theme directory?

Comment: Man, I hate bad theme authors. I digress. Since you want to change anchors (a repeating element), you'll want to add the font size property on the page you need it on, directly above your `.blog-menu` element. view my updated answer, i'll put the code you want there.

Comment: OK thanks.  But I'll need a little more hand-holding as I've never done this before.


>> you'll want to add the font size property on the page you need it on...

I'm trying to edit a menu that appears on every page of my website.  So where exactly do I need to insert the code?  i.e. what file(s) exactly do I need to edit?

Comment: OK that seemed to work!

I'm using the Hemingway theme (using a child them).  The blog-menu element seems to be generated in header.php, byL: <ul class="blog-menu">.  I added your code before it and the change was made.  I guess I need to copy the parent header.php to my child theme folder, and make this edit?

Comment: Deleted my previous comment to avoid email spam since it helped you solve your problem. And yes, copying `header.php` to the child theme, and adding the CSS there will work for you.

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere! The issue you were running into, again, is just a poorly planned theme. A child theme's style sheet includes the parent's `style.css` before all of it's CSS, so normally, just adding the style after the include will override the parent's styling attributes. The issue you were having is that the parent theme had some style affecting the `.blog-menu` anchor element's font size, with an `!important` keyword, which was overriding your style, even when you added the `!important` keyword.

Comment: Got it.  Is there a way I can quickly pinpoint this issue in the future?

Comment: You can use something like Chrome or Firefox's built in Element Inspector, and go through the style application tree, which shows the file source and crosses off ignored styles, in order.

Comment: I used Chrome's inspect element feature.  I was able to isolate the element and attribute in-question.  From Element Inspector I was able to change the font size, and have Chrome display it properly.  But when I made the necessary edit to my style.css the page did not register any css change.  Inspect Element appeared exactly the same as well--there was no strike through text or anything like that.  It made troubleshooting very difficult.